# is the DATA statement needed in modern Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, obsolete

I kind of know the behaviour of the **data** statement in fortran. However I don't know if there is any situation where it is prefered or it should be avoided

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you define "prefered" or "should be avoided"? As it is, the question could be read as seeking opinion such as "I don't like data statements because...", which makes the question off-topic here.

Comment: there are some statements that were needed in the early days but now there are better ways of doing things and they only remain part of the standard because they aren't a complete No-Go and because of back-portability reasons. I don't know if the data statement is one of them.

Comment: Indeed the Fortran standard contains a list of obsolescent features and several editions of the standard removed (deleted) a number of certain features. DATA statement, when used in the declaration part of a program unit, is **not obsolescent**. However, there are reasons to avoid even some of those features that are not in this list. But StackOverflow is not a place to discuss Fortran programming style issues, these are often opinion based and subjective.

Comment: The word "recommended" in the title is really problematic. This site is simply not for personal recommendations and there are no official style guides and recommendations from different books often differ.

Comment: Ok, I understand that if SO is not intended for question on style-guides my question is completely off-topic, should I close it?

Comment: I think this question is very close to being on-topic, as there are useful things to say about the data statement and its differences from "modern" features.  Changing the title may help.

Comment: Now, after the edit, the title says something completely different from the body of the quesion.

Comment: Usually, I prefer to avoid data statements, but from time to time, I find it useful, for instance when initializing only a part of array.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like `data` statement when the initialization of my variables would be more clear with it than by normal assignment. For example:

```fortran
type gene
  character :: gene
  integer :: depth
  integer :: delta
end type

type(gene) :: pool(8)

! initializing in a data statement looks nicer in this case
data pool%gene  / '#', 'U', 'R',  '+',  '-',  '*',  '/',  '^'/
data pool%depth /  0 ,  0 ,  1 ,   2 ,   2 ,   2 ,   2 ,   2 /
data pool%delta /  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  -1 ,  -1 ,  -1 ,  -1 ,  -1 /
```

Comment: I'm not too sure the data statements are more clear than the corresponding assignments like `pool%gene = ['#', 'U', 'R',  '+',  '-',  '*',  '/',  '^']`.  However, the fact that the data statement gives explicit initialization is an important difference.  (If you're relying on being able to use data statements closer to the declaration when an assignment cannot be, that'll be worth stressing.)

Comment: Yes, francescalus. Maybe I didn't choose a good example because a normal assignment would look almost equal to the data statement in this case. Maybe a better example could be initializing a upper-triangular matrix or something like that, tha would be much simpler as a data statement than an assignment.

Comment: I still dont get why in an upper-triangular matrix initialization it would be easier with data than with normal assignment

Answer (score 1):

The data statement is not obsolescent. However, its use amongst executable statements has been obsolescent since Fortran 95. Appendix B of the [latest Fortran standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf) gives details of obsolescent features.

> B.3.5  DATA statements among executables. The statement ordering
>   rules allow DATA statements to appear anywhere in a program unit after
>   the specification statements. The ability to position DATA
>   statements amongst executable statements is very rarely
>   used, unnecessary, and a potential source of error.

On page 140 of Modern Fortran Explained (the green edition from 2011, not the newer red edition, which I don't have), Metcalf, Cohen & Reid write

> We recommend using the type declaration statement rather than the data
>   statement, but the data statement *must* be employed when only part of
>   a variable is to be initialised.

Given that two of the authors are members of the [WG5](https://wg5-fortran.org/) (which is responsible for the development of Fortran --- actually maybe all three authors are members; I'm not sure about Michael Metcalf), we can say with a fair degree of certainty that the data statement should be avoided unless initialising part of a variable, before the executable statements in a program unit.